# multiple branch if else statements

Tags: if-statement, char

I'm trying to identify a single character as a letter either upper case or lowercase. I'm having trouble with the logic of the if else statement. any help would be really appreciated. When it runs it will now print whether it is upper or lower case.

```
String x = "";

if (Character.isLetter(x)) {
       System.out.println(x + " is a letter.");
   }
   else if (Character.isUpperCase(x)) {
       System.out.println(x + " is upper case.");
   }
   else if (Character.isLowerCase(x)) {
       System.out.println(x + " is lower case.");
   }
```

Comment: Your only mistake is due to the early closing of the first `if` clause, @Joe Hope you understand my explanation, :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
if (Character.isLetter(x)) {
   System.out.println(x + " is a letter.");
   if (Character.isUpperCase(x)) {
      System.out.println(x + " is upper case.");
   }
   else if (Character.isLowerCase(x)) {
      System.out.println(x + " is lower case.");
   }
}
```

Comment: Great. Can you tick this as answer? And up vote it if you like the answer.. :)